# CUDA BFS Giant Graph (seg.fault)

Tags: c, cuda, segmentation-fault, breadth-first-search

I'm making a test on a BFS algorithm on CUDA ( wich I know that has some syncronization problems, but it's part of my work to test it anyway ) but i'm having problems on using (or creating?) 1M+ size graphs.

Here's the code I use to create them:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


#define GRAPHSIZE 1000000

struct Node 
{
    int begin;     // comeco da sub-string de vizinhos
    int num;    // tamanho da sub-string de vizinhos
};



int getSize()
{
int size,arcs;

    printf("Size of the graph: \nNodes:\n>>");
    scanf ("%d", &size);

return size;
}



void createEdges(int graphSize, int* Edges)
{

int j,value, aux, rndIdx;

int edgesSize = 2*GRAPHSIZE;

srand(time(NULL));



printf ("\nGS : %d\n", graphSize);

j = 1;

    for (int i=0; i < edgesSize; i++) //first it creates an ordered array of edges
    {

        if (j < GRAPHSIZE)
        {
        Edges [i] = j;
        j++;
        }
            else
            {
            j=1;        
            Edges [i] = j; 
            j++;
            }

    }



    for (int i=0; i < edgesSize; i++) //now, it randomly swaps the edges array
    {

    rndIdx = rand()%graphSize;

    aux = Edges[rndIdx];
    Edges[rndIdx] = Edges [i];
    Edges [i] = aux;

    }

} 


int main ()
{

int size,graphAtts[2];

int edgesSize = 2*GRAPHSIZE;

int Edges[edgesSize];

struct Node node[GRAPHSIZE];

FILE *file;



printf("____________________________\nRandom graph generator in compact format, optmized for CUDA algorithms by Ianuarivs Severvs.\nFor details about this format read the README. \n");

//size = getSize(graphAtts);

//printf ("%d,%d",size,arcs);

createEdges(GRAPHSIZE,Edges); // or size?

/*
    for (int i = 0; i < edgesSize ; i ++)
    {
    printf ("-- %d --", Edges[i]);
    }   

*/

printf("\nEdges:\n");
for (int i=0; i < edgesSize; i++) 
printf("%d,",Edges[i]);


    for (int i=0,j=0 ; i < GRAPHSIZE; i++,j+=2) // now, completes the graph
    {
    node[i].begin=j;
    node[i].num=2;
    printf ("\n node %d : begin = %d, num = 2",i,j); 
    }

printf("\n");

//writes file:
file = fopen ("graph1M.g","wb");
fwrite (&Edges, edgesSize * sizeof(int),1,file);
fwrite (&node, GRAPHSIZE * sizeof(struct Node),1,file);
fclose(file);


    for (int i = 0; i < edgesSize ; i ++)
    {
    printf ("-- %d --", Edges[i]);
    }   


    for (int i = 0; i < GRAPHSIZE ; i ++)
    {
    printf ("* %d *", i);
    }


}
```

And here's my BFS code (on CUDA):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cutil.h> 

#define GRAPHSIZE 1000000

struct Node 
{
    int begin;     // begining of the substring
    int num;    // size of the sub-string 
};

__global__ void BFS (Node *Va, int *Ea, bool *Fa, bool *Xa, int *Ca, bool *parada) // memory races on both Xa and Ca
{

    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (tid > GRAPHSIZE)
           *parada=true;


        if (Fa[tid] == true && Xa[tid] == false)
        {
        Fa[tid] = false; 
        Xa[tid] = true;
        //__syncthreads(); // this solves the memrace problem as long as the threads are all on the same block
                   for (int i = Va[tid].begin;  i < (Va[tid].begin + Va[tid].num); i++) // Va begin is where it's edges' subarray begins, Va is it's                                                                        number of elements
            {             
                int nid = Ea[i];

                if (Xa[nid] == false)
                {
                Ca[nid] = Ca[tid] + 1;               
                Fa[nid] = true;             
                *parada = true;
                }

            }                   

        }

}

// The BFS frontier corresponds to all the nodes being processed at the current level.


int main()
{

    // for the time couting:
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    float time;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);


    FILE * file;

    printf("\nLoading graph file...\n");


    struct Node node[GRAPHSIZE];
    int edgesSize = 2*GRAPHSIZE;
    int edges[edgesSize];


    file = fopen ("graph1M.g","rb");
    printf("abriu");    
    fread (&edges, edgesSize * sizeof(int),1,file);
    fread (&node, GRAPHSIZE * sizeof(struct Node),1,file);
    fclose(file);

 //For file read test propouses only:

/*
    for (int i = 0; i < edgesSize ; i ++)
    {
    printf ("-- %d --", edges[i]);
    }   


    for (int i = 0; i < GRAPHSIZE ; i ++)
    {
    printf ("* %d *", i);
    }
*/  



    bool frontier[GRAPHSIZE]={false}; 
    bool visited[GRAPHSIZE]={false}; 
    int custo[GRAPHSIZE]={0}; 

    int source=0; 
    frontier[source]=true; 

    Node* Va; 
    cudaMalloc((void**)&Va,sizeof(Node)*GRAPHSIZE); 
    cudaMemcpy(Va,node,sizeof(Node)*GRAPHSIZE,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 

    int* Ea; 
    cudaMalloc((void**)&Ea,sizeof(Node)*GRAPHSIZE); 
    cudaMemcpy(Ea,edges,sizeof(Node)*GRAPHSIZE,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 

    bool* Fa; 
    cudaMalloc((void**)&Fa,sizeof(bool)*GRAPHSIZE); 
    cudaMemcpy(Fa,frontier,sizeof(bool)*GRAPHSIZE,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 

    bool* Xa; 
    cudaMalloc((void**)&Xa,sizeof(bool)*GRAPHSIZE); 
    cudaMemcpy(Xa,visited,sizeof(bool)*GRAPHSIZE,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 

    int* Ca; 
    cudaMalloc((void**)&Ca,sizeof(int)*GRAPHSIZE); 
    cudaMemcpy(Ca,custo,sizeof(int)*GRAPHSIZE,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 


    dim3 grid(100,100,1); //blocks per grid
    dim3 threads(100,1,1);  // threads per block




    bool para; 
    bool* parada; 
    cudaMalloc((void**)&parada,sizeof(bool)); 
    printf("_____________________________________________\n");
    int count=0;

    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    do{ 
        count ++;
        para=false; 
        cudaMemcpy(parada,&para,sizeof(bool),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);       
        BFS <<<grid,threads,0>>>(Va,Ea,Fa,Xa,Ca,parada);    
        CUT_CHECK_ERROR("kernel1 execution failed"); 
        cudaMemcpy(&para,parada,sizeof(bool),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); 


    }while(para); 

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);


    //printf("\nFinal:\n");
    cudaMemcpy(custo,Ca,sizeof(int)*GRAPHSIZE,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); 
 /*
    printf("\n_____________________________________________\n");
    for(int i=0;i<GRAPHSIZE;i++) 
        printf("%d  ",custo[i]); 
    printf("\n");

    printf("_____________________________________________\n");
*/

    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf ("\nTime for the kernel: %lf s \n", time/1000);
    printf ("Number of kernel calls : %d \n", count);


    file = fopen ("graph125MPar","w");


    for(int i=0;i<GRAPHSIZE;i++) 
        fprintf(file,"%d    ",custo[i]); 
    fprintf(file,"\n");
    fclose(file);



}
```

I'm having a segmantation fault while trying to run it for 1M+ graphs (please note that I used the changed the stack size of the sistem with the command ' ulimit -s 16384 ' on linux)

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use statically allocated host arrays for the graph, use dynamic memory allocation instead. Your `ulimit` command is setting the stacksize to 16384 kb, but you require something like `5*sizeof(int) + 2*sizeof(bool)` per graph entry which is probably 22 bytes per entry. It is pretty easy to see where you will run out of stack space with 1 million entries.

Comment: Yeah, I was running away from that solution (it's a harder implementation) but I think that'll be the only way out of the bugs

Comment: How is it a harder implementation? You have to change exactly three lines in you current code, and perhaps add three lines to deallocate the storage afterwards, and you are done.

Comment: My point is that handlig with pointers, mainly in parallel algorthms are usually a headache for me..